# Weird drawing lines on donut (Vid 3, level 1 with Blender Guru)

Tags: modeling, rendering

I am trying to make the donut following the tutorial by Blender Guru.

Just wondering why there are some weird lines on my donut before even getting to making the dripping, have you experienced something like this before?

Grateful to have your insights!

Comment: Can you update your question with a picture so we can see? I did this tutorial two months ago

Comment: So you've duplicated the top half and solidified it to create the bump. Was it before or after this action. Or did these lines start showing after you started pulling the icing to create the dripping effect?

Comment: “Weird lines“ is not enough information!  Please add a picture to your question.